# dangerouslySetInnerHtml doesn't update during render

Tags: reactjs

So I made a component for including content-editable components in my app. I copied it from some gist I believe, then edited to what i needed.

The code is below. When I edit it, it triggers updates on the parent just fine, but when I attempt to set props.html in the parent, it doesn't reflect in the UI.
FURTHER, the console.log shows that this.props.html is equal to '' a blank string, yet the UI doesn't update, and maintains the text that was originally in there.

I don't understand how this is possible... dangerouslySetInnerHtml = {__html: ''} should make it so the UI reflects an empty string... it feels like it should be impossible for it to show the old text.

```
var React = require('react');

var ContentEditable = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        //TODO: find where html=undefined and fix it! So I can remove this? Maybe I should keep this safety.
        var html = this.props.html || '';
        console.log('content editable render, html: ', this.props.html);
        return <div id="contenteditable"
            onInput={this.emitChange} 
            onBlur={this.emitChange}
            contentEditable
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}></div>;
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps){
        return nextProps.html !== this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
    },

    emitChange: function(){
        var html = this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
        if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {
            this.props.onChange({
                target: {
                    value: html
                }
            });
        }
        this.lastHtml = html;
    }
});

module.exports = ContentEditable;
```

(A little background, I'm trying to clear my input after submitting it to be saved. The clearing isn't working, hence this question.)

Comment: typically any data that could change, should be put in state on the parent and the child should use props which is passed down from the parent state, that way once you edit the state of the parent, React will re-render the children.

Comment: That's precisely how I'm attempting to do this.

Comment: Side note: `TODO: find where html=undefined and fix it!` .. try `console.log('html undefined',new Error().stack)`

Comment: I've had something similar https://jsfiddle.net/crl/eumxoudn/5/ type then press reset, it doesn't reset. wrapping the next props.html in new String() makes it work  /4

Answer (score 13):

I got a very similar problem using `contentEditable` and `shouldComponentUpdate`, it looks like there is a bug when resetting the innerHTML to the same previous value using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` function (or prop) (I think it does not work even if you insert the code without using it)  ... I suspect (this is just an idea) that React compares the last value set through `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with the new one you are trying to send and decides not to update the component because it is the same (even if the real innerHtml has changed due to user interactions, because those interactions does not trigger any state or props update on React).

**Solution:** The easiest solution I found was to use a different key each time I needed it to re-render. for example using `key={Date()}`.

**Example:** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50147/) you can find your code (I changed some of it to make it work), when you type '?' into the div, the text inside the ContentEditable component should become an empty string (i.e. ''), it works only once, the second time you type '?' won't work because the innerHTML for react will be the same to the one you're setting (i.e. an empty string so it won't update the component).

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50148/), I added the `key={Date()}` (this is the easiest way to show you that this work, but it is not the best way to set a unique key each time it re-render) to the editable component, now you can type any number of '?' and it will work.

Comment: For some reason, `key={Date()}` didn't work for me, but using Math.random() did.

Comment: I've seen this problem even if I set other state. For example, I tried `this.setState({edited: true})` in the `onInput` handler, then `edited: false` in `componentDidUpdate`. I assume the problem is there unless the new state becomes part of the new element, e.g. as an attribute. Still seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Nevermind, adding an attribute with, e.g., Math.random(), didn't help, either. I assume react looks at each part of the element individually.

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution that is probably better than generating random keys. Putting a key specifically on the div that calls #dangerouslySetInnerHtml, and not just on the component itself

```
<div class='wrapper'>    
<div key={this.props.thing.id} dangerouslySetInnerHtml={this.props.thing.content} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case here but make sure you always dangerouslyset html on div tag and never on span, p ... because if span element child is div, there will be a problem.

Solved rerender bug to me

Comment: This is not correct! The `<span>` element [permits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) all [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content), which also includes the span itself.

Comment: I should have been more precise, span cannot contain <div> inside which is likely to be present in HTML which we are setting.. only those elements can go inside span tag ->e <abbr>, <audio>, <b>, <bdo>, <br>, <button>, <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>, <data>, <datalist>, <dfn>, <em>, <embed>, <i>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <kbd>, <keygen>, <label>, <mark>, <math>, <meter>, <noscript>, <object>, <output>, <picture>, <progress>, <q>, <ruby>, <samp>, <script>, <select>, <small>, <span>, <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <textarea>, <time>, <u>, <var>, <video>, <wbr>

Answer (score 1):

Adding `key` property for an element with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` did resolve my issue.

As a key I used

```js
key={new Date().getTime()} // timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue (React 16) and used an approach suggested by [MLR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5560922/mlr) which consists in dropping `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and using `componentDidMount()` instead for the initial render and `componentDidUpdate()` for any subsequent renders.

**Solution here**, adapted to React 16: https://codepen.io/mlbrgl/pen/PQdLgb

These hooks would perform the same update, directly updating `innerHTML` from props:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.updateInnerHTMLFromProps();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.updateInnerHTMLFromProps();
}

updateInnerHTMLFromProps() {
  this.refEl.innerHTML = this.props.html;
}
```

This makes it clearer (for me at least) to see what is really going on, without having the false expectation that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` would keep the DOM in sync in all circumstances, as suggested by [Mike Woodcock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4792548/mike-woodcock) here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38548616/9408759.

For a complete view of the problem and both solutions outlined here, please check https://codepen.io/mlbrgl/pen/QQVMRP.

Comment: Im using `contenteditable` and `textContent`, but these seem to have the same problems. I've tried both `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate`, but neither worked the way I expected.

Answer (score 0):

My (very simple) React (version 16) app: It has a `contentEditable` `<div>`. 
It successfully re-renders this `<div>` upon a progression of submit button clicks. Instead of `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`, I used `ref={el => this.myRefElem = el}` with `componentWillUpdate(nextProps) { this.myRefElem.innerHTML = nextProps.myInputText; }` For me, `nextProps` was important for the proper value to re-render. See my app's project files, to see the rest of the required code. 
[CLICK-HERE](http://m-rooney.com/rjs-content-editable-div/)​ to see my React app. It has a button to download its (development mode) project files. It (basically) only has an index.js file. - - - This app was initiated by [mlbrgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9408759/mlbrgl), who asked me for an alternative technique.